# html5 type="date" do not show with ngmodel in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel

The **date** not binding in to the `input[type=date]`

```js
(function(){

var app = angular.module('tableApp',[ ]);
app.controller('tableController', function($scope){
 $scope.items = [
     { date: '12-March-2013', rate: 12.35, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '1-January-2011', rate: 60.54, name: 'Maanu meenu'},
     { date: '12-December-2014', rate: 12.56, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '14-November-2014', rate: 0.99, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '2-November-2014', rate: 4.00, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '16-February-2014', rate: 6.54, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '30-November-2014', rate: 60.32, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '5-May-2014', rate: 5.12, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '12-April-2014', rate: 8.99, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '18-November-2014', rate: 34.54, name: 'Manjeri mmanjeri'},
     { date: '28-June-2014', rate: 55.12, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '21-June-2014', rate: 99.54, name: 'Maanu meenu'},
     { date: '31-December-2014', rate: 15.50, name: 'Maanu meenu'},
     { date: '1-November-2014', rate: 34.05, name: 'Konu konu'},
     { date: '3-November-2014', rate: 45.00, name: 'Maanu meenu'}
 ];
});

})();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="tableApp">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover" ng-controller="tableController">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Member</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : 'rate'">
        <td>
          <input type="date" ng-model="item.date">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.rate">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: dates should be javascript date objects https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

Answer (score 0):

dates should be javascript date objects [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)

and note that this feature is not works in older angular versions. its working angular 1.3 and onwards

So you can try something like [angular-ui bootstrap datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)